# Wordpress - Display array data of a child

Tags: php, custom-field

I've used the wordpress plugin - [advanced custom field](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) and would like to show an array of a child, here's my code:

I'm using this code to show the custom fields data from a specific page ID's children:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'depth'        => 0,
    'child_of'     => 411 );
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of'));

foreach($pages as $post)
{
setup_postdata($post);
$fields = get_fields();
if($fields->company_name != "") : ?>
   <h2><?php echo $fields->company_name; ?></h2>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php
}

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This is the code I'm using to show the checkbox data of the page itself (i.e it's not a parent/child):

```
<?php $catNames = array( 'branding','creative','development','exhibition','packaging','print','seo','social_media','usability','web','advertising','campaign','content','feasibility','publishing','research','strategy');

    foreach($catNames as $name){
        if(in_array($name, get_field('categories') )){
            echo '<a href="/tags/design/'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'">'.ucwords($name).'</a>';       
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to combine the two together so underneath the H2 tag in the first code box I want to show the checkbox data of the child, how can this be done?

UPDATE:
When I add the checkbox code to the child code, I can't get the data to display, it's either blank or has an error.

This is the page I'm [working on](http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/tags/design/branding). The first thumbnail has been hardcoded, the second and third thumbnails should pick up the tags with the code above but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show the checkboxes that have been ticked (much simpler!!):

```
                    <?php
$categories = get_field('categories');
$elements = array();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    //do something
    $elements[] = '<a href="/tags/design/' . strtolower($category) . '" title="' . $category . '">' . $category .'</a>';
}
echo implode(',', $elements);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think you should ask that question here. This is answer. Just leave your answer part, and ask the question separately - [as you did](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6051039/278)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'depth'        => 0,
    'child_of'     => 411 );
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of'));
$catNames = array( 'branding','creative','development','exhibition','packaging','print','seo','social_media','usability','web','advertising','campaign','content','feasibility','publishing','research','strategy');
foreach($pages as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    $company = get_field('company_name',$post->ID);
    if( $company != "") {
       echo '<h2>'.$company.'</h2>';
       foreach($catNames as $key => $val){
            if(in_array($val, get_field('categories',$post->ID) )){
                echo '<a href="/tags/design/'.$val.'" title="'.$val.'">'.ucwords($val).'</a>';       
            }
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Can I put this on any page and it will show the children of page 411 and show their checkboxes (in theory!)? Also, I had only left the company variable in as there are about 8-10 different variables, could I just copy how you've done it for the company one?

Comment: Just tried the code, the checkbox answer don't appear. I don't think I explained well enough - it should be grabbing the checkboxes of the children, just like the company variable. Doesn't $post->ID grab the parent?

Comment: no the $post->ID is any child since you have `setup_postdata($post);`

Comment: Oh ok, it still doesn't work though.